# Not able to login after create the user in AD using Java

Tags: active-directory

I have written code using JNDI for creating users using `DirContext` in AD.
After I create the user I am not able to login with those credentials. When I manually reset the password for that user in AD, I am able to login.

Here I have placed my code for your reference,

```
Hashtable<String, String> ldapenv = new Hashtable<>();
ldapenv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapenv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.95.144.139:389");
ldapenv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ldapenv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,dc=Merck,dc=local");
ldapenv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Merck2017");

DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(ldapenv);

Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes();
// Create the objectclass to add
Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
objClasses.add("top");
objClasses.add("person");
objClasses.add("organizationalPerson");
objClasses.add("user");

// Assign the username, first name, and last name
String cnValue = new StringBuffer(user.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(user.getLastName()).toString();
Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", cnValue);
Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute("sAMAccountName", user.getUserName());
Attribute principalName = new BasicAttribute("userPrincipalName", user.getUserName()
        + "@" + "merck.local");
Attribute givenName = new BasicAttribute("givenName", user.getFirstName());
Attribute sn = new BasicAttribute("sn", user.getLastName());
Attribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", user.getUserName());

// Add password
Attribute userPassword = new BasicAttribute("userPassword", user.getPassword());

Attribute pwdAge = new BasicAttribute("pwdLastSet","-1");
Attribute userAccountControl = new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl", "544");

// Add these to the container
attributes.put(objClasses);
attributes.put(sAMAccountName);
attributes.put(principalName);
attributes.put(cn);
attributes.put(sn);
attributes.put(givenName);
attributes.put(uid);
attributes.put(userPassword);
attributes.put(userAccountControl);
attributes.put(pwdAge);

// Create the entry
try {

    context.createSubcontext(getUserDN(cnValue,"Merck-Users"), attributes);
    System.out.println("success === ");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error --- "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Please help me resolve the following issues:

1. How do I set AD user password while creating the user using the above code?
2. How do I set `userAccountControl` to `66048` in the above code?
3. How do I create the user enabled while using the above code?
4. How do I disable the option "user must change the password in next login" while creating the user in the above code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the answers, but this should get you started:

Passwords can only be set over a secure channel, like LDAPS (LDAP over SSL). Since you are connecting to port 389, that is not SSL and AD won't let you set the password. You must connect to the LDAPS port: 636. You may run into issues trusting the SSL certificate. I can't help much here since I'm not a Java developer, but there is an example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alextch/2012/05/15/how-to-set-active-directory-password-from-java-application/).

The answer to your second and third questions is the same: Accounts with no passwords are always disabled. Since you haven't set the password properly, the account will be disabled. Once you figure out how to set the password, you can also set `userAccountControl` to whatever you need.

You are disabling the "user must change password" option correctly: by setting `pwdLastSet` to `-1`. That's the right way to do it. But you may have to fix the other issues first.

Another important thing: I have created AD accounts in .NET, and I have found that I had to create the account first, then go back and set the password and set the `userAccountControl` attribute after. You may have to do the same.